# Row lock feature in Jhipster code

Tags: jhipster

I am using Jhipster and added few entity to my application. Now I want to add row lock feature in few of the transaction to my db. In Hibernate its being done by using session factory  as given http://javacompleteexamples.blogspot.in/2009/07/how-db-locking-system-works-in.html but I am not getting beginTransaction and session.get methord using Jhipster code

Answer (score 0):

Not really a JHipster question but rather a Spring Data question.
You could use the [@Lock annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#locking) on some method of your repository.